# Create time index of integers based on date values using Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pyspark, indexing

I have a pandel dataframe in spark,including dates for all items:

| Date | Item ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 34 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2 | 45 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2 | 87 |
| 2022-03-01 | 2 | 65 |
| 2022-02-01 | 3 | 11 |

I would like to create a new column (Time index) which are **INTEGER** values based on the date and it is ordered like dates are ordered.
Want I want:

| Date | Item ID | Value | Time index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 34 | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2 | 45 | 1 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2 | 87 | 2 |
| 2022-03-01 | 2 | 65 | 3 |
| 2022-02-01 | 3 | 11 | 2 |

How can I do that in pyspark?
Or in pandas?

If it's easier in pandas I can just convert the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas` try `rank`

```
df['new'] = df['Date'].rank(method = 'dense')
Out[61]: 
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    2.0
Name: Date, dtype: float64
```